# numba: X in dict(...,....).keys() vs X in list(dict(...,....).keys())

Tags: python, numba

I'm using:

```
In [18]: numba.__version__
Out[18]: '0.54.1'
```

this code works:

```
import numba
import numpy

@numba.jit(nopython = True)
def foo(sample_int):
    some_dict = numba.typed.Dict.empty(key_type=numba.types.int64, value_type=numba.types.int64)
    for row_idx in range(len(sample_int)):
        last_val = 0
        if sample_int[row_idx] in list(some_dict.keys()):
            last_val = some_dict[sample_int[row_idx]]
        some_dict[sample_int[row_idx]] = sample_int[row_idx] + last_val       

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sample_int = numpy.array([11,13,21,22])
    foo(sample_int)
```

but now if you remove the `list()` around `list(some_dict.keys())`, all hell breaks loose:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function contains>) found for signature:
 
 >>> contains(keys[DictType[int64,int64]<iv=None>], int64)
 
There are 22 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 22 did not match due to:
      Overload of function 'contains': File: <numerous>: Line N/A.
        With argument(s): '(keys[DictType[int64,int64]<iv=None>], int64)':
       No match.

During: typing of intrinsic-call at ...

...
```

my questions are:

1. why? Can it be fixed?
2. is there a loss of perf hit from this replacement of in .keys() by in list(.keys())? In pure python, I think, "in" is supposed to be faster for dicts than list, specially if the dict has many keys...

Comment: Have you tried just taking out the `keys` call? `sample_int[row_idx] in some_dict`

Comment: no I had not and it solves the problem! Care enuf to put it as an answer?

Comment: `... in list(some_dict.keys())` is really bad for performance as it create a list from all the key for each check (`O(n)` time). A `in some_dict` runs in constant time thanks to hash-maps (aka dict). As for the `... in some_dict.keys()` typing problem, this is a bit more complex: Numba visibly does not implement the `in` operator for the type returned by `some_dict.key()` which is a *view* of all the keys. It may worth it to create an issue as I am not sure this behaviour is intended by Numba developers... Not that the support of dicts in Numba is quite new and still rather experimental.

Comment: @JérômeRichard: 'Numba visibly does not implement the in` does that still hold if   
user2357112's proposed solution (`sample_int[row_idx] in some_dict`) works?

Comment: @user189035 Yes, because the `in` is not implemented for the type `keys[DictType[...]]` (ie. for `... in some_dict.keys()`) but it is implemented for `DictType[...]` (ie. for `... in some_dict`).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: ok thanks for the detail. I will post an issue on their gitlab.